# My MacBook Pro 13'' works only with 85w charger

Tags: macbook-pro, charging, power

I have a MacBook Pro 13'' mid 2014. My 60w charger stopped working yesterday (no green light, no AC charger detected in system information). However, when I tested the charger with another MacBook Pro 13'' everything looked ok.

Then I connected my MacBook Pro 13'' to a 85w charger from a 15'' and that one worked perfectly.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Either:

1. The two Macbook 13 draw different power due to normal conditions and your adapter won't work at all when a normal but high draw is needed. (i.e. replace your adapter)
2. The 60 W adapter is failing and it' bad luck that you got a few heads in a row and a few tails in a row - if you do enough tests 50% failure rate will happen with any MacBook. (i.e. replace your adapter)
3. Your MacBook is drawing / requesting more power than it should and needs a soft reset / SMC reset or repair. (i.e. service your Mac)